# Problem manipulating AM-GM with 3 variables

Tags: proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> For $a, b, c > 0$, prove 
>   $$
> \frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a} \ge ab + bc + ca.
> $$

I am not sure whether I should cube the 3-variable AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Have you tried Sos method?

Comment: I am not sure where to apply that, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Are you set on using AM-GM? It's pretty easy with [Engel's form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality). We get
$$\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a} \ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{ab+bc+ca}\ge ab+bc +ca.$$
The latter inequality is true because it is equivalent to $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge 0.$$

Comment: But this is C-S

Comment: @AnasA Yeah, that's why I started by asking if the OP definitely only wants AM-GM. CS can be proven by Lagrange's identity though, so it really just boils down to the trivial inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity . (This is just for illustrative purposes, as I prefer the quadratic discriminant proof of CS because it makes writing down the exact equality case easier)

Comment: Oh, sorry about the confusion. I was thinking of AM GM to solve it, but I think Engel's form works too.

Comment: @Tacquari yea and rearrangement gets it directly

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
ac(a+b)(a-b)^2+ba(b+c)(b-c)^2+cb(c+a)(c-a)^2 \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
and rearrange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need $AM\ge GM$.

Well by assume WLOG $a \ge b \ge c$ and thus $1/c \ge1/b \ge 1/a$ , by rearrangement (inequality)
$$\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a} \ge\frac{a^3}{a}+\frac{b^3}{b}+\frac{c^3}{c} =a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ac $$

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:
$$\frac{P^2}{u}+\frac{Q^2}{v}+\frac{R^2}{w} \ge \frac{(P+Q+R)^2}{u+v+w}. u,v,w >0$$
So we have $$F=\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a} \ge \frac{(a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2})^2}{a+b+c}.$$
Use Mean-Power-ineq.:
$$\frac{(a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2})}{3} \ge \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^{3/2}$$
We get $$F \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}\ge ab+bc+ca$$
Lastly we have used $$a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 13.
Use AM GM three times.
$$5\frac{a^3}{b} + 6\frac{b^3}{c} + 2\frac{c^3}{a} \geq 13 \sqrt[13]{a^{13}b^{13}} = 13ab$$

If you have any questions I can answer :). Why I used 13 uses a simple trick, I can describe it to you.